# Why is this php code displaying json array without code to display it?

Tags: php, json, paypal

```
<?php

function pay()
{
        $data = '
    {
          "intent":"sale",

          "redirect_urls":
          {
            "return_url":"http://n1.lchs-is.org",
            "cancel_url":"http://n1.lchs-is.org"
          },

          "payer":
          {
            "payment_method":"paypal"
          },

          "transactions":
          [
            {
              "amount":
              {
                "total":"7.47",
                "currency":"USD"
              },

              "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
            }
          ]
    }
        ';


    //Start curl request
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set curl options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          "Content-Type: application/json",
          "Authorization: Bearer A101.lTxNCRX3B-vhQIN4991wdthA6SzCtPKganKXVOZta84hADs-25S5OGk4yyG-HLzR.lM-rDOIJAaEXGWhcYi2YF8yhnRy",
        ));

    //Display results
    $json = curl_exec($ch); // <------- It's displaying this array that it receives from curl right here
    curl_close($ch);
}
pay();

?>
```

I coded this PHP code to simply create a paypal payment, and when I run it, it displays the JSON Array, even when I coded it not to. Why is this so and how can I fix this?

Also any code I typed after executing the `pay()` function, is not executed. For example if I put `echo "test";` that line of code is not executed.

Answer (score 4):

You might need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`

For example

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Store value in string $response below
$response = curl_exec($curl); //execute and get the results
```

Comment: This is correct. `curl_exec` by default outputs the response to the browser. You need to set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to `true` (in this case `1`) in order to capture the response into a variable.